# How to save data to process later after stopping DirectStream in SparkStreaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am creating below KafkaDirectStream.

```
  val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
         ssc,
         LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
         ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topicsSet, kafkaParams))
```

Then saving the values as :

```
  val lines = messages.map(_.value)
```

Then stoping the streaming context when I have no further offset to consume as follows:

```
  lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      if(rdd.isEmpty()) {
        messages.stop()
        ssc.stop(false)
      } else {

      }
  })
```

Then I am printing the `lines` as follows:

```
    lines.print()
```

Then I am starting stream as:

```
    ssc.start()
```

It is working fine. It reads rdds and prints top 10 and stops messages stream and stop streaming context. But then when I execute the same line `lines.print()` it throws an exception saying cannot do new inputs, transform, or outputs after stoping streamingContext.

How do I achieve my goal? I am running it in a spark-shell not as a binary (mandatory requirement).

Here is what I actually want to achieve:

1) Consume all json records from the kafka topic.

2) Stop getting further records (It is guarenteed that after consuming, there won't be no new records added to Kafka topic, so don't want to keep proessing no records.)

3) Do some preprocessing by extracting some fields from the JSON fields.

4) Do further operation on the preprocessed data.

5) Done.

Answer (score 0):

when you are calling "lines.print()" again, its trying to call the transformation "messages.map(_.value)" again. As you stopped the context its failing.

Save the lines variable by performing an action before stopping the context.